# Is there any specific configuration needed for Oraclize ethereum-bridge to support oraclize_newRandomDSQuery()?

Tags: truffle, oracles, ganache

I am using ganache-cli and ethereum-bridge in order to test oraclize locally. Other calls to oraclize, such as `oraclize_query("URL","...")`,
work just fine. I am only having trouble with `oraclize_newRandomDSQuery()`.

So is there anything specific that needs to be done to use the `oraclize_newRandomDSQuery()`?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to see if that method works when not using a local ethereum network? Say on Rinkeby or the mainnet?

Comment: It works on both rinkeby and ropsten

Comment: Hmm okay. Are you sure you setup the bridge properly and that the query you want is supported by Oraclize's bridge? I know for some attestation proofs, not all proofs are supported for all query types so perhaps the same is for the oraclize bridge? If you are still stuck you can check out their gitter https://gitter.im/oraclize/ethereum-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to Oraclize's Random Datasource, it is only supported on public networks, such as the Ethereum Mainnet, and the general testnets, such as Rinkeby, Kovan, Ropsten. Reasoning behind this is that the on-chain verifiable Random DS proof is dependent on being able to fetch some network information, and that of course is not possible with a non-public network, so only public ones can be supported.